# iOS - CollectionView rotation responds slow

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a collectionView where I am using the following to manage rotation of the cells:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion:  { context in

                self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.finalizeCollectionViewUpdates()
            })
        }
    }
```

I see that the size change on rotation is very slow ( takes ~ 3- 4 seconds ). Is there a better way to get smoother rotation transition? I have dynamic cell sizing from sizeForItemAtIndexPath, code is :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var width = CGFloat()

        if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            width = collectionView.frame.size.width - 2.0 * margin
        }
        else if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                width = floor(collectionView.frame.size.width - 14.0 * margin)
            }
            else {
                width = floor(collectionView.frame.size.width - 6.0 * margin)
            }
        }

        let post = self.postListForLoggedInUserFromRealm?.posts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
        if let description =  post?.description {

            let rect = NSString(string: description).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.8, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: CGFloat(titleFont))!], context: nil)

            var knownHeight : CGFloat = 64

            if(post?.imageURL != nil && post?.imageURL != "") {

                guard let imageURL = NSURL(string: (post?.imageURL!)!) else { return CGSize(width: width, height: rect.height + knownHeight )}
                if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((imageURL as CFURL), nil) {
                    if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {

                        let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! CGFloat
                        let imageMaxHeight: CGFloat = (CIConstants.DeviceType.DeviceTypePhone == deviceType ) ? 400 : 700
                        let imageHeight =  pixelHeight > imageMaxHeight ? imageMaxHeight : pixelHeight
                        knownHeight = knownHeight + CGFloat(imageHeight) 

                        return CGSize(width: width, height: rect.height + knownHeight)
                    }
                }
            }

            return CGSize(width: width, height: rect.height + knownHeight)
        }

        else if(post?.imageURL != nil && post?.imageURL != "") {
            var knownHeight : CGFloat = 10 + 44 + 8 + 44 + 10

            guard let imageURL = NSURL(string: (post?.imageURL!)!) else { return CGSize(width: width, height: knownHeight + 70)}
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, nil) {
                if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
                    let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! CGFloat
                    let imageMaxHeight: CGFloat = (CIConstants.DeviceType.DeviceTypePhone == deviceType ) ? 400 : 700
                    let imageHeight =  imageMaxHeight > 700 ? imageMaxHeight : pixelHeight
                    knownHeight = knownHeight + CGFloat(imageHeight) 
                }
            }

            return CGSize(width: width, height: knownHeight)
        }

        return CGSize(width: 850, height: 70)
    }
```

Any suggestions would be truly appreciated! Thanks for your time :)

EDIT: When I use this code, the delay is gone but I lose the margins ( on left and right of collectionView) in Portrait mode.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition:  { context in

                self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.finalizeCollectionViewUpdates()
            })
        }

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }
```

Comment: Sometime it happen because of your cellforitem has some heavy loading task like image loading which might be larger you can check that is it causing problem or not by return blank cell without any data loading

Comment: I am using sdWebImageView to set the images which I think loads the images asynchronously and also caches them.